# merging unrelated items into a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have a collectionView for a group chat application that displays messages from an array of messages.

I want to additionally show when new users join or leave the chat as a label with their names in it that has to be inserted into the collectionView at the appropriate place when they join.

I'm really not sure what mechanism to use in order to add users labels into my collectionView.

Would I have to further separate my collectionView into more sections everytime a user joins and break down the messages array?  Or is there an easier way to insert non-related items.

Comment: An `UICollectionView` can manage different `UICollectionViewCell`, so you could use an other `UICollectionViewCell` for showing that a user has shown. Your data model should have an "order" (sort by a NSDate ?).

Comment: my data model presently is an array of messages sorted by date.  would i need to change this to an array of anyObject and merge the non-message cells into this array?

Comment: You could, yes, and in `collectionView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, check the class of `yourArray[indexPath.row]`, and `dequeue` the correct custom `UICollectionViewCell`.

Comment: I will try doing that.  Just wish there was an easier way that could keep the unrelated arrays isolated from one another.  Thx for your help.